# wp_commentdata: error in documentation?

Tags: wpdb

The page http://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description#Table:_wp_commentmeta
lists the meta_id field of the `wp_commentdata` table as being both `PRIMARY KEY` and
`DEFAULT NULL`. But a primary key cannot be null, not even in MySQL, AFAIK, as running
the following code in phpmyadmin confirms:

```
CREATE TABLE Baz (x bigint unsigned primary key default null);

#1067 - Invalid default value for 'x'
```

So, is there an error in the documentation?

Thanks.

Comment: If the answer was helpful to you, then consider accepting it. See »[What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)« and/or »[Why is voting important?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote)«, more information about the [wordpress.se] model is available at the [help].

Answer (score 0):

The Codex is written by humans, so it could be wrong. But what you are missing is the column »Null« beforehand, as you can see it is empty or yes. To determine what that does mean we are taking a look into the source. This you should do first if you are in doubt about the correctness of the documentation. We are looking into the [`schema.php`](https://github.com/markjaquith/WordPress/blob/master/wp-admin/includes/schema.php#L75) file and see:

```
CREATE TABLE $wpdb->commentmeta (
  meta_id bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  comment_id bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  meta_key varchar(255) default NULL,
  meta_value longtext,
  PRIMARY KEY (meta_id),
  KEY comment_id (comment_id),
  KEY meta_key (meta_key)
) $charset_collate;
```

Which means if the column value for »Null« isn't »Yes« it's not `NULL` but `NOT NULL`.